# Microsoft Graph keeps raising InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph for authentication. For testing, I uploaded the PHP REST example to a webspace - locally, it works, but on the server, it keeps raising

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message     'Required option not passed: "access_token"'
in vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Token/AccessToken.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(755): League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken->__construct(Array)
#1 vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Provider/AbstractProvider.php(562): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->createAccessToken(Array, Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Grant\AuthorizationCode))
#2 oauth.php(60): League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\AbstractProvider->getAccessToken('authorization_c...', Array)
#3 {main} thrown in vendor/league/oauth2-client/src/Token/AccessToken.php on line 63
```

Does anybody know why I keep getting this error message, or at least point me into the right direction to fix it?

Code sample:

```
$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    clientId                => 'client-id', // replaced for security reasons
    clientSecret            => 'client-secret',
    redirectUri             => 'redirect_uri',
    urlAuthorize            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    urlAccessToken          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    urlResourceOwnerDetails => '',
    scopes                  => 'openid profile'
]);

$accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        code             => $_GET['code']
    ]); // raises the exception
```

Comment: As I'm sure you already noticed, the reason is that the access_token parameter is not set. Could you point to the sample, or add the relevant code paths? That would make it easier to see what the difference between local and server might be.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). An example of the code you're calling would be helpful here as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this error gets fixed if I insert

```
$prepared['access_token'] = $prepared['id_token'];
```

into AbstractProvider::getAccessToken, right before the call to `createAccessToken`. I'm not entirely sure if this is a bug in the OAuth2 library, but it works for me now.

Comment: what is $prepared ?

Comment: @MitulMarsoniya It's a variable inside `AbstractProvider::getAccessToken`.